# Python "print" coming after while loop even though it's physically before?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm messing around with some python (in eclipse using dynamic language toolkit) and even though I have the print command a line before my while loop, I have to enter the values and type "done" before it prints everything, then it will print the prompt and the values. I've tried using the raw_input() built in prompt as well to no avail. Is this just an issue with the editor or is something wrong with my code?

```
class squareNums:
def __init__(self):
    self.nums = []
    self.getInput()

def getInput(self):
    print ('Enter values individually, then type "done" when finished')
    while True:
        var = raw_input()
        if var == 'done':
            break
        else:
            self.nums.append(var)
    print self.nums
```

squareNums()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's a "feature" of the environment you're executing it in. When run from the command line, I see just what you'd expect:

```
$ python /tmp/tester.py
Enter values individually, then type "done" when finished
123
123
132
123
done
['123', '123', '132', '123']
```

If I had to guess, I'd say that your terminal is buffering all output until the program ends, and then flushing it all to the screen at once.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the confirmation. I'm doing all this on my school macbook so I can't really change that I have to write all this in eclipse. Honesty if it were up to me I would be SSHing into my home server and writing it on VIM, but they blocked all sort of ssh.

Comment: You can easily run it from the Terminal even if you're editing it in Eclipse.

Comment: They have terminal blocked too :(

Comment: What @kindall said. Your Mac has vim and python commands installed, so feel free to open a Terminal.app window and hack away to your heart's content. In fact, that's exactly the combination I used to save out and run your app on my own MacBook.

Comment: Wait, what? That's terrible. What's their stated reason for doing such a silly thing? Out of curiosity, can you navigate to /usr/bin in Finder and run programs from that folder?

Comment: I don't know, it's a high school. In fact, I'm surprised they don't even have this website blocked for "forums". It's insane how locked down these things are: about 40% of websites are blocked and basically every "utilities" app is blocked, even some parts of system preferences are locked. We can't even turn the wifi off because they want to be able to go in and remotely watch our screens at all time. We can't even run .jar files... EDIT: I checked /usr/bin, they all say "you don't have permission to run terminal"

Comment: I hate to hear that because it sounds like they're working hard to prevent you from learning. I don't want you to get in trouble, but if you were my kid, I'd tell you to see if you could access an IDE-in-a-browser service like https://www.nitrous.io and get your own educational VM.

Comment: Yeah, it's kinda disappointing. I used to know the EFI code through a friend that cracked his, but they've recently upgraded the macbooks and it's virtually impossible now. I can access nitrous.io, I'll have to check it out. Thanks!